# Is it true that the order of spacelike events depends on an observer? Does that mean block universe is true?

Tags: time

[image: the order of events from a stationary observer]
[image: the order of events from a moving observer]

So I was thinking, as philosophers do, if even the past and the future is relative and the order of events can change, then block universe must be true. Is my reasoning right or wrong?

Comment: Yes, the time ordering of spacelike events depends on the frame of reference, but spacelike events can not affect each other causally, so it is a conventional ordering anyway. No, it does not imply [block universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternalism_(philosophy_of_time)), it is just one of several alternatives mentioned there. Some philosophers believe that the distinctions between the block universe and the alternatives amount to a purely verbal debate about the use of tenses, see [Lombard](http://archive.clas.wayne.edu/Multimedia/Philosophy/files/LBL%20Time%20for%20a%20Change.pdf).

Comment: It implies a block universe if you assume the only alternative to a block universe is some form of [presentism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/presentism/) in which there is an objective truth about what is happening in the present moment (with present things having a special ontological status), and you also assume that the lack of any physically preferred definition of simultaneity implies no metaphysically preferred definition. But there's no reason a presentist couldn't deny the latter, saying there is an objective present, but no empirical way to determine true simultaneity.